# Android views and fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I recently created a new app with a navigation drawer base.

The app has a few main sections, one of them being a ListView of items.

The app would then drill down to individual item details page when a ListItem is clicked.

This is roughly how the app is currently laid out:

```
+ MainActivity
|---- ActivityMain Layout
   |---- NavigationDrawer Fragment
   |---- FrameLayout
      |---- TopSection1 Fragment / TopSection2 Fragment / TopSection3 Fragment
```

When I want to make a new layout whose parent is `TopSection1`, would it be better to start a new activity or replace the Fragment in FrameLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new activity if you want the item to appear as a child of TopSection1. Replace the fragment if you want the item to appear as a sibling of TopSection1.

Comment: Would it be possible, then, to still retain the Navigation Drawers?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of your drawer doesn't need to change depending upon contents on screen, then it will be better to use fragments, because when you launch a new activity you'll have to redo all the stuff related to drawer that you did in last activity as drawer will not be retained in new activity